# exceptions openning Angular standalone project in VS2022

Tags: angular, sdk, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem creating or openning Angular standalone project in Visual studio 2022. I tried to install SDK but without success ! it says there is a javascript sdk not found !
no ideas on the net
Have you an idea please ?

*Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier projet. **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk\Sdk** introuvable. Vérifiez qu'un SDK .NET suffisamment récent est installé et/ou augmentez la version spécifiée dans global.json. System.AggregateException: Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Une tâche a été annulée.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you require to create/open an Angular project with Visual Studio 2022? Why not VSCode? Also, in order to create/use Angular apps, you need to have install the @angular/cli globally, as well as @nodeJs

Comment: We want to have all projects in the same solution. we dont have problem with vscode on the other hand but still a need to have this architecture